# Datagridview_cellvaluechanged only updates on second try

Tags: vb.net, winforms

DirtyStateChanged lets me commit immediately when I click the checkbox

```
Private Sub dataGridView4_CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles DataGridView4.CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged
    If DataGridView4.IsCurrentCellDirty Then
        DataGridView4.CommitEdit(DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.Commit)
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub DataGridView4_CellValueChanged(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView4.CellValueChanged

    For c As Integer = 2 To DataGridView4.ColumnCount - 1

        If DataGridView4.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(c).Value = True Then

            'Disable this persons' row on datagridview5
            Dim aName As String = DataGridView4.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(0).Value
            For Each dRow As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView6.Rows
                If dRow.Cells(0).FormattedValue = aName Then
                    dRow.ReadOnly = True

                    For Each cell As DataGridViewCell In dRow.Cells
                        dRow.Cells(cell.ColumnIndex).Style.BackColor = Color.LightGray
                    Next
                    'DataGridView6.Update()
                End If
            Next
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

When I click a checkbox on datagridview3, it should update the row on datagridview5 with a new backcolor and readOnly.

What seems to happen is it does not seem to work the first time clicking the checkbox. It does work perfectly on the second try though.

How can I make it validate on the first try?

Comment: @varocarbas The checkbox works by a single click but to make `CellValueChanged` by a single click you should handle `CellContentClick` and call `CommitEdit`. It makes `CellValueChanged` raise immediately after click. But as you said, the code seems to work as expected and I removed my answer because I didn't know `CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged` will do the trick too.

Comment: @RezaAghaei I saw your deleted answer but didn't read it. The OP's approach is a bit weird (for checkbox columns, `CellContentClick` or `CellClick` or similar is certainly the right approach) and I misunderstood it. But just one thing: with your approach (`CellContentClick`) you don't need to use `ComitEdit` for anything. The recommendation for the OP would be: just rely on a more adequate event (like `CellContentClick`, as you propose) and forget about `CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged`, `CommitEdit` and all that.

Comment: Thank you both for answering. It seems though even placing everything inside `CellContentClick`, it still requires me to do two tries for the other datagridview to update. If you guys would like a video, I can make a quick screen capture.